# how to apply theme according to api level

Tags: android

[image]

when using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"` image stretched
but when using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` so image are show perfact why this image are strech?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/journal_log_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/journal_entry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_save"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_small_add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_delete"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_small_save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_trash" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` so this type of images shown
[image]

Comment: can you show your XML code?

Comment: Could you post the relavent parts of your XML layout please?

Comment: xml code perfact work on android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change theme and try

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/journal_log_actionbar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/transparent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/journal_entry"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_save"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_small_add" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/journal_actionbar_menu_delete"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_small_save" />
```